# Convenient way of upgrading java version like npm

Tags: java, java-6

In node.js, one can use npm to upgrade package version conveniently with a single command line. In java, is there a similar and convenient way to upgrade the jdk and jse to the latest version? Something like this;

> $ jpm update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no direct way for JDK like that.

In windows you can use the java update manager to update the java version. In linux environment you can use the method mentioned in https://askubuntu.com/questions/183867/how-do-i-update-oracle-java-7-jdk-and-jre